# Why 'getopts' within a function fails to work?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

```
function readArgs() {
    while getopts "i:o:p:s:l:m" OPTION; do
        case "$OPTION" in
            i)
                input="$OPTARG"
                ;;
            o)
                output="$OPTARG"
                ;;
            ...
        esac
    done
}

readArgs

if [[ -z "$input" ]]; then
    echo "Not set!"
fi
```

This is always giving me `Not set!` but if I comment out the lines `function readArgs() {`, `}` and `readArgs`, it works. Why?

Also,

```
input="$OPTARG"
echo "$input"
;;
```

does not work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`getopts` is parsing the arguments to the `readArgs` function, and you're not giving that function any arguments.

Try with:

```
readArgs "$@"
```

Answer (score 8):

`getopts` relies on the `OPTIND` variable being initialized to 1. Either do

```
readArgs() { OPTIND=1; ...
```

or

```
readArgs() { local OPTIND; ...
```

Comment: This is only necessary if there are multiple invocations of the function.

Comment: The OP did not describe the container of the function. I use these methods for functions I write in my .bashrc

Comment: Although this answer did not answer the OPs question directly, it does come up on a search for why getopts doesn't work in a function, and was very useful in debugging my code (also for functions in my .bashrc)